# Handle standby mode

Tags: blackberry, notifications

Is it possible to handle when BlackBerry device is going standby or wake?

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so question will be marked as a resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the options you can use the [SystemListener2](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html) interface. It has a method [backlightStateChange](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html#backlightStateChange%28boolean%29), which contains the "true" if the backlight is turned on, and "false" - otherwise.

This is not exactly what question is about, but can be used in some way.